# Expiration of Close Votes

Tags: feature-request, bug

As gleaned from a comment to a different meta question, I learned that close votes "expire" after a certain time period. It appears, though, that those who have voted to close a question are then prevented from voting again. Attempting to cast a close vote after the initial vote has expired results in a "you have already voted to close this question" message.

Is this expected/normal behavior? If so, it really makes appropriate community moderation difficult. See for example this question:
[Is file_exists() compatible with timthumb.php?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33197/is-file-exists-compatible-with-timthumb-php)

Obviously, it should be closed (TimThumb & `is_file_exists()` - completely agnostic to WordPress), but it never did get closed. But I cast a close vote a year ago, and now can't again.

Comment: I think this is one of those cases when logic scaled to larger network sites doesn't work too well for the rest.

Comment: So, what do we do about it - or, more specifically: how do we work around this network limitation?

Comment: +1 and: You should add [tag:feature-request]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [What Happened Here? Voted to Close 4 Days Ago, but No Close Votes Today?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56614/what-happened-here-voted-to-close-4-days-ago-but-no-close-votes-today):

> We now use a form of sliding expiration, so as long as close/reopen
>   votes keep arriving **at the rate of at least one every 4 days**, they
>   will not expire.
>
> Once the votes do expire, vote aging happens every 24 hours, so you
>   can expect the remaining very old close/reopen votes to expire at the
>   rate of 1 per day after that, *unless of course someone casts another
>   close/reopen vote* in which case the expiration timer resets to 4
>   days.
>
> Also, if the question has <= 100 views, no expiration on close (or
>   reopen) votes is done at all.

There are two solutions. Well, maybe …

1. Encourage our members to visit the [review queue for closed questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/review/close) more often. But how?
2. Ask the SE team to implement [this rule](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97581/145551) on our site:

> Close votes (and probably reopen votes) only expire after all of these conditions are met:
>
> 1. 4 days have passed since the *last* close vote.
> 2. The question has more than 100 views.